# How do I filter a list in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I've got a list `l`:

```
l: til 10
```

I want to show all values `<3`.

I tried this:

```
l . (l<3)
```

and

```
l[l<3]
```

But neither work. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `where` is what you're looking for here.

```
q)l:til 10
q)l where l<3
0 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through the use of the [where keyword](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/where/). The where keyword will return the indices of your list that meet your criteria.

To use your example:

```
q)l:til 10;
q)l[where l<3]
0 1 2
```

Comment: this is easier to read thanks